# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Practise' - Although this folder exists

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, python-module

Hi I have created a Project which has folder structure as below:

[Folder Structure in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwvlt.jpg)

Why am I getting below error when I run postAPIAutomation.py in VS Code?

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\Umang Bhatia\Documents\Udemy\BackEndAutomation\Practise\postAPIAutomation.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Umang Bhatia\Documents\Udemy\BackEndAutomation\Practise\postAPIAutomation.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Practise.postPayload import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Practise'
```

**the code for postAPIAutomation.py is as below:**

```
import requests
import json
from jsonpath import jsonpath
from Practise.postPayload import *

#Adding a book
add_book_res = requests.post(
    url= 'http://216.10.245.166/Library/Addbook.php',
    json= add_book_payload('Alchemist', 'gfgerg', 'Paolo Cohelo'),
    headers= {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)

print(add_book_res.status_code)
res_json = add_book_res.json()
res_book_id = res_json['ID']

#Deleting a book

delete_book_payload = requests.post(
    url = 'http://216.10.245.166/Library/DeleteBook.php',
    json= delete_book_payload(res_book_id),
    headers= {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)

print(delete_book_payload.status_code)
```

**The code for postPayload.py is as below:**

```
def add_book_payload(book_name,isbn,author):
    input_json = {
        "name": book_name,
        "isbn": isbn,
        "aisle":"227",
        "author": author
        }

    return input_json

def delete_book_payload(book_id):
    input_json = {
        "ID" : book_id
        } 

    return input_json
```

Answer (score 0):

added an empty `__init__.py` file in `Practise` folder so it would be treated as a package.

or do a relative import like

```
from .postPayload import *
```

instead of

```
from Practise.postPayload import *
```

Comment: I have created an empty ' __init__.py' inside Practise folder. Getting below error now: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Umang Bhatia\Documents\Udemy\BackEndAutomation\Practise\postAPIAutomation.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .postPayload import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package